# Deleting an object from an Array list through a selected item from a JComboBox

Tags: java, arraylist, jcombobox

I have a student enrolment system I am having trouble with. I'm trying to remove an object from an `ArrayList` by selecting it from a `JComboBox`.

```
public class Course {

 public List<Student> Students;
 public List<Module> Modules;

    public Course()
    {
         Students = new ArrayList<Student>();
         Modules = new ArrayList<Module>();
    }

public class Del_Student extends JFrame
{

  private Course newCourse;
    public Del_Student(Course aCourse)
    {
        newCourse = aCourse;
        JButton btnDel = new JButton("Delete");
        JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        JComboBox studentsBox = new JComboBox();
        studentsBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(185,25));

    for(int i=0; i<newCourse.Students.size();i++ )
    {
        String p = newCourse.Students.get(i).getFirstName();
        studentsBox.addItem(p);
    }

      btnDel.addActionListener
    (
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newCourse.Students.remove(studentsBox.getSelectedItem());
            }
        }
    );
```

I have added a string from the object to show on the `JComboBox`, so what I am trying to do is select that item (shown by Students name) and then delete the selected item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help anyone else with a similar problem, I solved the solution by doing the following:

```
    btnDel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < newCourse.Students.size(); i++) {
                if (newCourse.Students.get(i).getFirstName().equals(studentsBox.getSelectedItem()
                        .toString())) {
                    newCourse.Students.remove(i);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student Deleted");
                    studentsBox.removeAllItems();
                    for (int t = 0; t < newCourse.Students.size(); t++) {
                        String p = newCourse.Students.get(t).getFirstName();
                        studentsBox.addItem(p);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't you compare String's with .equals() instead of the "==" operator? Just wanted to point that out if it helps